# Split dataframe for train_test_split based on indexes

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to use train_test_split to get my train data to be the dataframe between indexes 31 and 39.
I want to write something like `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(faces.data, faces.target, test_size = 0.3)` where `faces` is `faces = sk.datasets.fetch_olivetti_faces()`

How can I select which indexes I want to go into my train data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @berkayln suggested, I'm not sure your train-test split strategy is advisable, but to split the data as you're suggesting, I believe you can use:

```
from sklearn import datasets

faces = datasets.fetch_olivetti_faces()

X_train = faces.data[31:40]
X_test = faces.data[np.r_[0:31, 40:400]]

y_train = faces.target[31:40]
y_test = faces.target[np.r_[0:31, 40:400]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give with fancy index easily:

```
X_train=faces.data[:number what you want]
 
X_test=faces.target[:number what you want]

y_train=aces.data[number what you want]

y_test= faces.target[number what you want:]
```

Comment: ```
X_train = faces.data[30:39]
X_test = faces.target[0:30]
y_train = faces.data[30:39]
y_test = faces.target[0:30]

clf = SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print("accuracy score:{:.2f}".format(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)))
```

Tried it like that but it is not working, are you sure nothing extra has to be set for the test/train

Comment: Why are you making test data smaller than train data? It's not logical. @KarinaK

Comment: Because that part of the data has the thing i want to train on. The error I get btw is y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (9, 4096) instead.